# Uncountable Kronecker Delta?

Tags: vector-spaces, notation, hilbert-spaces

If V and W are vector spaces of uncountably infinite dimension, they still have bases (according to axiom of choice).

Let basis sets be $\{v_x\}_{x \in X}$ and $\{w_y\}_{y \in Y}$, and define a set of linear transformations $\{l_{x, y}\}$ by $l_{x, y}(v_{x`}) = w_y$ if $x = x'$ and $=0$ otherwise.

I have only been able to find references to the use of integers or rationals for the Kronecker Delta. Is it a valid use of the Kronecker Delta to say  $l_{x, y}(v_{x`}) = \delta_{x, x'}w_y$, and are there any references for this ?
As a secondary question, if this is not valid, why not and what should one use instead ?

(For context, the set $\{l_{x, y}\}$ is linearly independent in $L(V, W)$ and is a basis if $V$ is finite dimensional and not a basis if V is infinite dimensional).

Comment: You can certainly define $\delta$ for arbitrary index sets. Continuity has nothing to do with it.

Comment: @ZhenLin Thanks for that, I amended the title. Do you have any reference to KD being used in this way ?

Comment: You don't need any reference, just check that $l_{x,y}$ is linear, it is elementary. If I tell you that $2+3=5$, will you ask me for a reference?

Comment: @AlexM. It isn't the linearity of $l_{x,y}$ that's the question but the usage of the Kronecker Delta for uncountable indices. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta for example defines it for integers and by extension to rationals, but not for greater infinities. P.S. if I needed a reference for 2 + 3 = 5 I would use Halmos's Naive Set Theory.